# Update item in child adapter in nested recycler view from activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer, android-seekbar

I have a nested `recyclerview` in my activity as following:

[image]

Activity xml has `recyclerview` **(Parent)**-> recycler view  **adapter's xml** has another `recyclerview` (Child)

I am using a `media player` with `seek bar` in my `child adapter`.
I have setup the media player in my **activity** to handle `onDestroy` and `onPause` methods. But I want to pass the `mediaPlayer.currentPostion` to the **child** **adapter**.

How can I update the **progress** of `media player` from **activity** to my `child adapter view`?

I tried doing `mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged` and set current position in recyclerview's model FROM ACTIVITY but it may be an expensive task as the media player's progress is updated in 100 milliseconds.